# PIL Module Error

Tags: python, linux, attributeerror, python-imaging-library

I get the following error running the simple python script below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/python/folder/pil_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    im = Image.open('screenshot.png')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'
```

I run Debian Wheezy with KDE.
I have installed pillow via pip.

The script ran well on my previous system, so I suspect the issue
lies outside of my source code.

I feel slit up and have no idea where to start to solve that issue.
Just reinstalling pillow did not do the job for me.

What else could I do?

```
from PIL import Image


im = Image.open('screenshot.png')
left = '10'
top = '10'
right = '10'
bottom = '10'


im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))  # defines crop points
im.save('screenshot.png')
```

Comment: please post the **full text** of the traceback. As a first guess, did you name your script `Image.py` or `PIL.py`?

Comment: Thanks MattDMo. I have now included the full traceback. No, I named my scripts other than    Image.py or PIL.py.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason that the `Image` module wouldn't have the `open` function in it. Is this really all the code?

Comment: Hi Mark, yes this is -ALL- the code. Exactly copy pasted from my script. The failure certainly lies somewhere outside of the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

It appears uninstalling 'pillow' and install 'pil' did the job for me:

```
sudo pip uninstall pillow
sudo pip install pil
```

This is strange in so far as I thought installing pillow via pip must have included PIL automatically.

I do not know why. But it works now!

Comment: never use sudo. It will *eventually* corrupt your system's python installation. you can use conda or virtualenv to have a separate python for your other works, and it doesn't need any `sudo` to install your libraries.